# Removing everything inside squared brackets in pandas series or dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, brackets

Good day, is it possible to remove everything that's inside *including* the squared brackets?
Thanks in advance

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Santiago [1]','Madrid [2]','Barcelona [2]']})
df
```

> City
>   0 Santiago [1]
>   1 Madrid [2]
>   2 Barcelona [2]

**Desired output:**

> City
>   0  Santiago
>   1  Madrid
>   2  Barcelona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` + `strip`

```
df.City=df.City.str.split('[').str[0].str.strip()
df
        City
0   Santiago
1     Madrid
2  Barcelona
```

Comment: Thanks again, since it was my first question I didn't know there was a way to check the answers.

Answer (score 1):

YOBEN_S's answer is perfect. I am just adding an alternative where you don't have to use `strip()` by just using `split()` which splits the string by the white space in between.

```
df.City=df.City.str.split().str[0]
df
        City
0   Santiago
1     Madrid
2  Barcelona
```

EDIT : As Nick commented, this wouldn't work with cities containing white spaces in between. Here's an alternative if you want to separate using white space

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Santiago [1]','Madrid [2]','Barcelona [2]','New York [2]','India and China [10]']})
df.City=df.City.apply(lambda x : " ".join(x.split()[:-1]))
df
              City
0         Santiago
1           Madrid
2        Barcelona
3         New York
4  India and China
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex could work here as well ... get all characters before the `[` :

```
df['extract'] = df.City.str.extract(r'(.*(?=\[))')

       City         extract
0   Santiago [1]    Santiago
1   Madrid [2]      Madrid
2   Barcelona [2]   Barcelona
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with oen or more [xxx] appearing at anywhere in your string.

```
df.City.str.split('\[.*\]').str.join('')
```